# I keep getting ERR_ABORTED 405 on fetch(url) after deploying my website on vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm using fetch() to send an object from the client to the server, It worked fine on localhost:8080, but after deploying on vercel I cant seem to get it to work again.

Client: (when i used localhost:8080)

```
export async function saveToDB(obj) {
    let objStr = await JSON.stringify(obj)
    await fetch('http://localhost:3000/', {
        method: `POST`,
        headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json' },
        body: objStr,
    })
}
```

saveToDB runs when a certain button is pressed, it worked fine on localhost.

Server:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    // do stuff here
})

app.listen(port, (err) => { // port is assigned 3000 at the top of my code
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`server running on port ${port}`)
})
```

Client: (after deploying to vercel)

```
export async function saveToDB(obj) {
    let objStr = await JSON.stringify(obj)
    await fetch('https://[name].vercel.app/', { // i also tried https://[name].vercel.app:3000/
        method: `POST`, 
        headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json' },
        body: objStr,
    })
}
```

when i used https://[name].vercel.app:3000/ in the fetch i kept waiting for around a minute then it gave me a runtime error, then I removed the port and it always give me a 405 error now.

Exact error now:

```
index.js:601 POST https://[name].vercel.app/ net::ERR_ABORTED 405
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you literally posting to `[name].vercel.app` or is `[name]` replaced with your actual subdomain in the real code?

Comment: @ray not literally its replaced with the actual subdomain

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Render.com to deploy the backend only as a webservice and Vercel for the front end only and it worked.